# Android Studio won't start a new project

Tags: android, android-studio

I installed Android Studio IDE... but after I click "New Project" I get this error saying that my SDK version is out of date or I'm missing templates, please make sure your have version 22! But I updated my android SDK tools to that version when I had the ADT bundle. What should I do??

Answer (score 2):

In Android Studio, go to Configure -> Project Defaults -> Project Structure -> Platform Settings (SDK) choose the Android SDK, set the build target and click on apply. ﻿